# windicss not generating font-size, instead its generating color

Tags: css, tailwind-css, windicss, unocss

```
// base.css
:root {
    --grey: grey;
    --success: green;

    --xl: 20px;
}
```

and in my component

```
// vue sfc
<h1 class="bg-$grey text-$success text-$xl">You did it!</h1>
```

the css for text-$xl is generating as

```
.text-\$xl {
    color: var(--xl);
}
```

how to force it to generate as `font-size: var(--xl)`???

my uno config is

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    Unocss(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With your setup just use `font-size-$xl` instead of `text-$xl`

But I would move all custom colors/sizes to the unocss config file.
After that `text-xl` will grab your xl value for sure.